# Multi-Column Selector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5, user-controls

I am searching for some hybrid of ComboBox and ListView and I am wondering why there exists nothing like that, although I feel it's a quite natural wish to have it.

In more detail: 
A WPF ItemsControl should have an ItemsSource of all applicable items.
These items have multiple properties, say ID:int, Name:string and Description:string.
Now my ItemControl should:

1. Show these three properties as nicely aligned columns in some combobox-like drop-down
2. Provide some way of quickly finding an item by just typing text into a single textbox (without specifying, which property shall be searched). This should either select the first match or filter the items hiding all non-matching ones.

Key is that the control is perfectly usable without a mouse, but also provides some "explorer"-mode, if the user does not remember the perfectly identifying ID but only parts of some description or name.
A configurable "Search-Function" would be nice, and it would be no problem if you would need to explicitly state all the properties to be included in a search or display function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such control so far, but you can certainly make one easily,

Create a C# Custom Control and define control template as Expander containing a DataGrid/ListView.

You can define dependency properties of your custom control as needed for ListView and do templatebinding for them. Expander's header should be bound to selected item's text or some sort of text representation of your objects.

Alternative:

Add a GRID inside Item Template and define its column definitions. And you can specify multi column values in the GRID easily.

```
<ComboBox>
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CustomerEmail}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding CustomerPhone}"/>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

By applying widths correctly, and giving margins to textblock, you can create multicolumn list to be displayed easily. Dont forget to TextSearch.SearchPath property in order to be able to select item by keyboad.

Comment: Sounds good, indeed. Starting from the expander makes it much easier than trying to persuade the ComboBox to do what I want. 
Of course, I hoped for something ready-to-use and tested by some community, but maybe I'll give it a try to create it on my own.

Comment: Well... I tried, but quickly recognized that this way I will have to reimplement all those nice ComboBox-Features.
I guess it will be easier to wrap a ComboBox together with some event-triggered helpers and end up in the control that satisfies my needs.

Comment: I added one more alternative to the answer by simply just using itemtemplate.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a starting point considering the display part. 
So you stick to the ComboBox, I guess I got you wrong there.
Actually, I got somewhere about this already, only with SharedSizeGroups instead of fixed widths. The trouble is, that TextSearch.SearchPath defines exactly one search path, you can not search for say the second column by typing. And the ComboBox only selects the first match, it does not filter the results. So the second part of my question is still open.

Comment: I think for 2nd part, you will only need to make a new control extending Expander because changing combobox's control template and adding textbox inside it to filter results could be little difficult because all functionalities of combobox will be lost or will behave irradically. I did exact same approach in flex by using additional popup control with list inside it.